# How to reduce size of the loader?

Tags: css, progress, loader

I want to reduce size of a `loader` viz in the `snippet`.

> What I want is to reduce its size around `10-20%` proportionately.

Please guide me into this so I can do it by myself in future.

Here's my `code`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var progressbar = $('#progress_bar');
  max = parseInt(progressbar.attr('max'), 10);
  time = (1000 / max) * 2;
  value = progressbar.val();

  var loading = function() {
    var $ppc = $('.progress-pie-chart');
    if (value >= max) {
      value = 0;
      $ppc.removeClass('gt-50');
    } else {
      value += 1;
    }

    addValue = progressbar.val(value);

    $('.progress-value').html(value + '%');
    var deg = 360 * value / 10;
    if (value > 5) {
      $ppc.addClass('gt-50');
    }

    $('.ppc-progress-fill').css('transform', 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)');
    $('.ppc-ball').css('transform', 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)');
    $('.ppc-percents span').html(value + '');
  };

  setInterval(loading, time);




});
```

```css
/* Pie Chart */

.progress-pie-chart {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #024369;
  position: relative;
}
.progress-pie-chart.gt-50 {
  background: red;
}
.ppc-progress {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: calc(50% - 100px);
  top: calc(50% - 100px);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  clip: rect(0, 200px, 200px, 100px);
}
.gt-50 .ppc-progress {
  clip: rect(0, 100px, 200px, 0);
}
.ppc-progress-fill {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: calc(50% - 100px);
  top: calc(50% - 100px);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  clip: rect(0, 100px, 200px, 0);
  background: red;
}
.ppc-ball {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.ppc-ball:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgba(82, 180, 237, 1);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(82, 180, 237, 1) 0%, rgba(7, 120, 219, 0) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, rgba(82, 180, 237, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(7, 120, 219, 0)));
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(82, 180, 237, 1) 0%, rgba(7, 120, 219, 0) 100%);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(82, 180, 237, 1) 0%, rgba(7, 120, 219, 0) 100%);
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(82, 180, 237, 1) 0%, rgba(7, 120, 219, 0) 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(82, 180, 237, 1) 0%, rgba(7, 120, 219, 0) 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#52b4ed', endColorstr='#0778db', GradientType=1);
  top: -7px;
  left: 85px;
}
.gt-50 .ppc-progress-fill {
  clip: rect(0, 200px, 200px, 100px);
  background: #024369;
}
.ppc-percents {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: calc(50% - 173.91304px / 2);
  top: calc(50% - 173.91304px / 2);
  width: 173.91304px;
  height: 173.91304px;
  background: #052b4e;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
}
.ppc-percents span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2.6em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fc7114;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(248, 94, 41, 1);
}
.pcc-percents-wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.progress-pie-chart {
  margin: 50px auto 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" data-ride="carousel">

  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <!-- Carousel items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>First slide label</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Second slide label</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Third slide label</h3>
          <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr class="transition-timer-carousel-progress-bar" />

<div style="margin:0 auto;">

  <div class="bar_container">
    <div id="main_container">
      <div id="pbar" class="progress-pie-chart" data-percent="0">
        <div class="ppc-progress">
          <div class="ppc-progress-fill"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ppc-percents">
          <div class="pcc-percents-wrapper">
            <span>0</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ppc-ball"></div>
      </div>
      <progress style="display: none" id="progress_bar" value="0" max="10"></progress>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you saying you just want the circle to be smaller? @vivekkupadhyay Why add those `code blocks` in the edit to places that are not code at all?

Comment: yes exactly. I just want the smaller circle

Comment: And if you have any other loader look like my loader in code snippet plx share with me. Thnx.
(My English is too weak plx don't mind)

Comment: How about just change all the 200px and 100px in the CSS to whatever you want it to be? Where did you find this carousel, I'm pretty sure you didn't write it yourself?

Comment: yes i already try to change all 200px and 100px but it did'nt change in size it looks so ugly, And yes you are right i found only circular red loader then i'll take help from one of stackoverflow member to convert it in this shape b/c i'm newbee in js or css i just started my career so that's why i need seniors guide like you and all stackoverflow members

Comment: Changing all the sizes, including all the 200px and 100px, works just fine, as it should. You will just need to change all pixel sizes in the CSS to whatever you'd like them to be. All the sizes are defined in the CSS, so that is where you will change them. Please try to go through the CSS once more, and check the example I posted in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing all the 200px's and 100px's and the other pixel sizes in the CSS works just fine. See the snippet, I made it half the size here.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var progressbar = $('#progress_bar');
  max = parseInt(progressbar.attr('max'), 10);
  time = (1000 / max) * 2;
  value = progressbar.val();

  var loading = function() {
    var $ppc = $('.progress-pie-chart');
    if (value >= max) {
      value = 0;
      $ppc.removeClass('gt-50');
    } else {
      value += 1;
    }

    addValue = progressbar.val(value);

    $('.progress-value').html(value + '%');
    var deg = 360 * value / 10;
    if (value > 5) {
      $ppc.addClass('gt-50');
    }

    $('.ppc-progress-fill').css('transform', 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)');
    $('.ppc-ball').css('transform', 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)');
    $('.ppc-percents span').html(value + '');
  };

  setInterval(loading, time);




});
```

```css
/* Pie Chart */

.progress-pie-chart {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #024369;
  position: relative;
}
.progress-pie-chart.gt-50 {
  background: red;
}
.ppc-progress {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  clip: rect(0, 100px, 100px, 50px);
}
.gt-50 .ppc-progress {
  clip: rect(0, 50px, 100px, 0);
}
.ppc-progress-fill {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  clip: rect(0, 50px, 100px, 0);
  background: red;
}
.ppc-ball {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.ppc-ball:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgba(82, 180, 237, 1);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(82, 180, 237, 1) 0%, rgba(7, 120, 219, 0) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, rgba(82, 180, 237, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(7, 120, 219, 0)));
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(82, 180, 237, 1) 0%, rgba(7, 120, 219, 0) 100%);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(82, 180, 237, 1) 0%, rgba(7, 120, 219, 0) 100%);
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(82, 180, 237, 1) 0%, rgba(7, 120, 219, 0) 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(82, 180, 237, 1) 0%, rgba(7, 120, 219, 0) 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#52b4ed', endColorstr='#0778db', GradientType=1);
  top: -7px;
  left: 40px;
}
.gt-50 .ppc-progress-fill {
  clip: rect(0, 100px, 100px, 50px);
  background: #024369;
}
.ppc-percents {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: calc(50% - 73.91304px / 2);
  top: calc(50% - 73.91304px / 2);
  width: 73.91304px;
  height: 73.91304px;
  background: #052b4e;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
}
.ppc-percents span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2.6em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fc7114;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(248, 94, 41, 1);
}
.pcc-percents-wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.progress-pie-chart {
  margin: 50px auto 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" data-ride="carousel">

  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <!-- Carousel items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>First slide label</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Second slide label</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Third slide label</h3>
          <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr class="transition-timer-carousel-progress-bar" />

<div style="margin:0 auto;">

  <div class="bar_container">
    <div id="main_container">
      <div id="pbar" class="progress-pie-chart" data-percent="0">
        <div class="ppc-progress">
          <div class="ppc-progress-fill"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ppc-percents">
          <div class="pcc-percents-wrapper">
            <span>0</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ppc-ball"></div>
      </div>
      <progress style="display: none" id="progress_bar" value="0" max="10"></progress>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you soo much for helping me out of this problem and thnx for guiding me how to decrease or increase this loader size.